# Firebase (Web) twitter authentication redirects to login page (using React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase twitter authentication for the web redirects to login page without errors, instead of proceeding with login and redirecting to dashboard.

The problem is that it only happens sometimes.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

I have deployed the app here https://tamurowebapp.firebaseapp.com/login

the onClick handler for my twitter button is

```
{() => auth.signInWithRedirect(twitterAuthProvider).catch(error => this.setState({registerError: error.message}))}
```

I'm importing the provider as follows

```
import { auth, twitterAuthProvider } from '../../firebase.js
```

and I'm exporting the auth and provider for a firebase config file as follows

```
export const auth = firebase.auth()
export const twitterAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider()
```

I've also attached a bin of all the code for the login page. I'm not sure it's relevant but just in case https://repl.it/HbT0/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When handling authentication changes, the best way to avoid race conditions is to use `onAuthStateChanged()`. In your case, `render()` is probably firing before the authentication cycle is complete sometimes.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged